# How do I print number labels vertically as a count next to output integers vertically?

Tags: python, printing, label

Sorry I don't have any code.  When I print the integers they are vertical.  My question is, how do I label these integers with numbers vertically?

My current output is:

```
     2
     8
     9
     10
```

What I would like to happen is:

```
    1) 2
    2) 8
    3) 9
    4) 10
```

Comment: You don't have any code but you have a current output?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
mylist=[2,8,9,10]
number={}
for x in range(len(mylist)):
   number[x+1] = mylist[x]
for item in number:
    print('{}) {}'.format(item, number[item]))
```

You can also just iterate the numbers and print:

```
mylist=[2,8,9,10]
number={}
for x in range(len(mylist)):
   print('{}) {}'.format(x+1, mylist[x]))
```

If you want a good data format for operations like these, you can use pandas.